# Type test in F# on sequences, general equality test

Tags: .net, f#, equality

I am trying to test equality of two elements. Why do I get the error: "does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion", in the first pattern match:

```
    let eq a b = 
        match (a,b) with 
        | :? (seq<_>*seq<_>) -> Seq.map2( fun xA xB -> xA=xB ) a b 
                                |> Seq.fold( fun res elem -> res && elem ) true
        | :? _ -> a=b
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I get the error: "does not have
>   any proper subtypes and cannot be used
>   as the source of a type test or
>   runtime coercion", in the first
>   pattern match

Because the type `System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Object>,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Object>>`, a.k.a. `(seq<obj>*seq<obj>)` does not have any subtypes (the `Tuple` class is sealed).

Comment: Actually, to be pedantic I think it's because `'a * 'b` doesn't have any subtypes.  That is, `match obj() with | :? (seq<_>*seq<_>) -> 0` compiles, but `match (1,'c') with | :? obj -> 0` doesn't.

Comment: Okay but but what about casting a KeyPairValue, for example the below returns false:

        let d = new Dictionary<int,int list>();
        d.Add(2,[3;4;5;6])
        d.Add(0,[3;5;2])
        let f = box(Seq.head d)
        f :? KeyValuePair<_,_>
Thanks

Comment: You said 'box', so you're trying to match against `obj`, which has plenty of subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is rather ugly. I'm very curious about more elegant approaches.

There is no (seq*seq) type. You'll have to test each parameter individually. Something like

```
match (a,b) with
| (:? seq<_> as seqa), (:? seq<_> as seqb) -> ...
```

But this gives a compiler error, because the types of a and b need more type annotation. But this would constrain the parameters in such a way that you cant do something like eq 2 2.

The snippet below would fix this:

```
let eq a b = 
    match (box a, box b) with 
    | (:? seq<_> as seqa), (:? seq<_> as seqb) -> 
        printfn "comparing sequences..."
        Seq.map2 (fun xA xB -> xA = xB) seqa seqb |> Seq.forall id
    | _ -> printfn "comparing default..."
           a=b
```

But the result of comparing two sequences is not what's expected:

```
> eq {1..10} {1..10};;
comparing default...
val it : bool = false
```

It jumps to the second match clause. This is because the compiler restricted the types seq<_> to seq and it's fed two seq.

In order to compare two sequences, they need to be converted to Seq's like this:

```
> eq1 (Seq.map box {1..10}) (Seq.map box {1..10});;
comparing sequences...
val it : bool = true
> eq1 (Seq.map box {1..10}) (Seq.map box {1L..10L});;
comparing sequences...
val it : bool = false
```

This said, I think it's a rather ugly hack. I'd suggest writing a sequence comparison function that only tests sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need this - it may be easier to store the two sequences in a collection type that automatically implements structural comparsion (element-wise compare) such as ordinary F# list.

However, you could write this using untyped `IEnumerable` this gives you a way to avoid the need for specifying generic type parameter for `seq<_>` in the pattern matching (which is not easily possible). You need a simple helper to convert non-generic `IEnumerable` to `seq<obj>`:

```
open System.Collections

let ofUntyped (a:IEnumerable) =
  seq { let en = a.GetEnumerator() 
        while en.MoveNext() do
          yield en.Current }
```

[**EDIT**: You can use `Seq.cast<obj>` instead of the helper I wrote]

The rest of the code is almost the same as your original version. You just need to look for `IEnumerable` in the pattern matching and then convert the sequence using `ofUntyped`:

```
let eq (a:obj) (b:obj) =  
  match a, b with  
  | (:? IEnumerable as ae), (:? IEnumerable as be) -> 
    Seq.map2( fun xA xB -> xA = xB) (ofUntyped ae) (ofUntyped be)
      |> Seq.fold( fun res elem -> res && elem ) true 
  | _ -> a = b
```

Comment: I believe 'Seq.cast<obj>' is identical to your 'ofUntyped'.  Also LINQ's 'Cast' and 'OfType'.